# javascript function to return an object , but it does not , variable get destroyed outside xhr.onload function

Tags: javascript

this has may be discussed over several times. but just to make the idea clear. I want my function to return an object. but the way I wrote the code, it does not return the object. I tried other ways. but variable gets destroyed when it comes to outside of xhr.onload function. please help me understanding the problem

```
function hhtprequest(id)
{
    var pobj = function(image,name,price){
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","ajax/productinfforsell.php?pid="+id,true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

              new pobj(data.imagefile,data.name,data.price);

        }

    }

    xhr.send();
    return pobj;
}
console.log(hhtprequest(9));
```

Comment: `it does not return the object` So what does it return? You have to explain everything if you want help, this tells us nothing

Comment: Okey, first of all thanks for your response .   it does return nothing . except the function phototype itself . whatever the fucntion signature and value in it , it does return all . i want it to be returned like javascript object . for example   '{"image":image,"name":name,"price":price} '  i know i am making some silly mistake but unable to catch that .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
var pobj = {};
function handleData(obj){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
function hhtprequest(id)
{
    var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","ajax/productinfforsell.php?pid="+id,true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            pobj.image = data.imagefile;
            pobj.name = data.name;
            pobj.price = data.price;     
            handleData(pobj);         
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hhtprequest(id)
{
    var pobj = function(image,name,price){
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","ajax/productinfforsell.php?pid="+id,true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        var obj =new pobj(data.imagefile,data.name,data.price);

        }

    }

    xhr.send();
    return obj ;
}
console.log(hhtprequest(9));
```

Comment: sir , i guess its the same code as i posted / what changes did you make here

Answer (score -1):

```
new pobj(data.imagefile,data.name,data.price);
```

You need to assign this object in a var and then return that var.

Comment: Was this intended to be a comment to your answer?  FYI, dumping code without explanation doesn't make for quality answers.  You need to explain why it solves the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18813067)

Comment: @AhmadF are you sure it doesnot provide the answer

Comment: As per given problem user want to return an object but he was returning a function named as "pobj ". He has created an object but not assigned to any variable.So in my solution, I have created a variable and object assigned to this variable.

var obj =new pobj(data.imagefile,data.name,data.price);